# Artifactory: Copy artifact from one repo to another via API using cURL

Tags: curl, artifactory

Using the [Copy Item](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/copy-item) documentation, I have attempted to copy a file from one artifactory repository to another. However, every attempt results in a `400 Bad Request` return (and no JSON response from the API). I can use GET requests to get information about the Artifactory server via the API, and when logged into the web UI I can perform the same file copy manually. So I am assuming that, given the 400 return code, I am simply constructing my cURL command incorrectly.

Here is my cURL command (`-v` used to get verbose output):

```
curl -s \
    -X POST \
    --user "${ARTIFACTORY_USER}:${ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY}" \
    -d "to=prod-deb/${pkg_path}" \
    -d "dry=1" \
    -G "${ARTIFACTORY_API_URL}/copy/testing-deb/${pkg_path}" -v
```

Since the API docs specify formatting the request using a querystring, `-G` is used.

The result of running this command with verbose output is:

```
*   Trying <REDACTED>:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to artifactory.mydomain.com (<REDACTED>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1

<snip> cert info </snip>

* Server auth using Basic with user 'myuser'
> POST /artifactory/api/copy/testing-deb/path/to/pkg.deb?to=/prod-deb/path/to/pkg.deb&dry=1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: artifactory.mydomain.com
> Authorization: Basic <REDACTED>
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Thu, 29 Feb 2024 18:26:06 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host artifactory.mydomain.com left intact
```

The docs are unfortunately not that great, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

This server is running Artifactory Professional, version 6.23.23.

Answer (score -1):

To copy the artifacts/folders from one repository to another repository kindly execute the below cURL commands:-

1. To copy artifact:-

   **> curl -uadmin:'password' -XPOST "http://ART-URL/artifactory/api/copy/source-repo-name/artifact-name?to=target-repo-name&dry-run=1" -Lvv**
2. To copy the folder:-

   **> curl -uadmin:'password' -XPOST "http://ART-URL/artifactory/api/copy/source-repo-name/folder-name?to=target-repo-name/folder-name&dry-run=1" -Lvv**

The above commands will copy the artifacts/folder from one repository to another. For more details refer to our official [documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/copy-item).

Comment: Please read the actual post. Thanks.